# Picture thumbnails on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

Is there a way to view picture thumbnails on Ubuntu within Nautilus?

NOTE: the photos I am trying to view sit on a network drive without WRITE permission.

Comment: http://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/tag/thumbnails/

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/539902/how-can-i-view-thumbnails-of-pictures

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a new Nautilus instance and choose `Edit` from the menu. Now got to `Preferences` and switch to the `Preview` tab. You can choose between never displaying thumbnails, always and only on local files systems. I guess always should work for you.

Also, when it says "Only Files Smaller Than" in the same Preview tab, try changing the sizes to see if that helps. If made too small, it may not display all the thumbnails properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something in your question (in which case, please, elaborate) but the answer is yes. Just use the "Icon View" in Nautilus (the default AFAIK).

[image]

Comment: Tried it to no avail: could it be because it is a network drive without WRITE permissions?